# Memcache in python

Tags: python, memcached

I want to memcache an xmldata using python,also needs to update the cache with the refreshed xmldata retreived from webserver,could any one help me with sample code.

Comment: did you look at python-memcached? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

This could be of some help:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/

Quite a few nice code samples are included.